# How to implement webRTC in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, xmpp, webrtc

I have successfully implemented xmpp Connection and text chatting by using xmpp in my application. Now want to implement video calling by using webRTC. I don't know the exact procedure for it. I have searched about it but, I'm unable to implement the video chat.
If anyone have any idea about the procedure, please help me.

Comment: Check out OpenTok, they have an iOS SDK too. https://tokbox.com/

Comment: OpenTok provide a sdk for connecting with their server, I have my own server and want to implement video chat by using my server.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

look at the webrtc.org code. The library compiles with bindings for iOS, and the app (appRTCDEMO) provides a full example for iOS. It's a great start.